# Linking An Access DataBase to Sql Building and building VB InterFace

Tags: sql, vb.net

Hey IO have an old access data base and I have reeated the New data base using SQL Server Management Studio but all the data is still in the Access data base and I was wondering how to link these two. I have been trying to create the linked tables in access using the ODBC tool but none of the table I want are appearing?

Was wondering if anyone has any ideas on how I can do this?

Also I then have started to create the front end of the database using Visual Studio but cant get the fields to populate as the SQL database currently has no data linked to it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of linking tables  have you considered using SQL Server Express (you did not mention what the 'new database' is, assume Access?) and the data import wizard to port the data to SQL Server? You get all the tools by downloading 'SQL Server with tools' from Microsoft.   And use SSMS for management functions, it is much easier than the Visual Studio interface.

Comment: So see I am creating the new data base threw SQL and I am looking to take the Information from the access database and be able to use it threw A Visual Studio Interface as I am building the GUI in visual studio?

Comment: If you have SQL Server then you have SSMS and the Import and Export Data utility. Have you used that? It is made to do what you are describing.